# Word counter issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, word-count

I have a text area where I do a countdown on `.keyup()` but it although it does what it supposed to it lets the user to believe that there id *1 character left* to type, yet the length of the text area has reached the limit. Here is my code:

```
<script>
     var w_limit = 3000;
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#comment').keyup(function(e) {
            el = $(this);
            if(el.val().length >= w_limit){
                el.val( el.val().substr(0, w_limit) );
            } else {                    
                $("#word-count").text(w_limit-el.val().length + ' characters left');
            }
        });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: You should really store `el.val()` once and reuse it (until you set it and need to get it again). As well as declare `el` with `var`. You also spelled `function` wrong in the `$(document).ready` part

Comment: There is a typo in your code `fucntion`. Apart from that it works here http://jsfiddle.net/XP4vp/.

Comment: @undefined It works until you get to the last character, then it never displays `0 characters left` - it sticks at 1. It's because of the `if`/`else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from your typos, you need to **always** run the `$("#word-count").text(stuff);` part. Here's it working without the `else`:

```
var w_limit = 20;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#comment').keyup(function (e) {
        var el = $(this),
            val = el.val();
        if (val.length >= w_limit){
            el.val( val.substr(0, w_limit) );
        }
        $("#word-count").text(w_limit - el.val().length + ' characters left');
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/eHstm/

(of course, I used a lower `w_limit` number for testing purposes)